# Combine Multiple excel sheets with different schema in a single excel sheet

Tags: alteryx

As a newbie to Alteryx this could be a very simple fix but I am struggling with many things.

I have about 7 excel sheets on the shared drive which I need to combine in a single excel sheet. (The excel sheet is in csv format).

However after giving the directory path I am not able to figure out 2nd and 3rd tool in the below screenshot. (I copied this Workflow from this community discussion). Can someone please explain me in simple words what wrong I am doing here and what I should be doing to not get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4VqJ.png)

Comment: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Knowledge-Base/Read-in-Multiple-Excel-Files-with-Multiple-Tabs-that-have/ta-p/51145

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have the file open in Excel (or something else) at the same time.